# Which is fast URLConnection or Socket

Tags: java, url

For getting data from remote url which connection type will work fast URLConnection or Socket.

Comment: Well, "the fastest" in most meaningful measures would be "which one can talk to the server without hacking together an HTTP request/parser by hand"? This of course assumes that HTTP is the desired protocol to use -- if it wasn't then where does URLConnection even fit in the picture? (One doesn't use URLConnection, as it's abstract, rather a subclass such as HttpURLConnection is used.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both have different purposes, depending upon your need

A socket can implement *almost* a duplex kind of functionality, whereas a url connection can connect to a given URI and read its content.

Comment: Could you explain more please?

Comment: URLConnection connects to a domain name with http/https, and Sockets connection to ip adress with a given port number?. As domain names are connected to an ip adress - aren´t URLConnection and socket then doing the exact same thing?

Answer (score 5):

Presumably you mean the java "URLConnection" library versus or raw Sockets.

As URL connection uses sockets internally then logically sockets should a little bit faster as http makes all the socket calls plus some overhead in handling the full protocol.

In practice I would expect very little difference. If you code up your own sockets interface  you will need to do most the extra processing carried out by the URL connection in order to make the sockets connection workable and reliable.

Also the java "URLConnection" library was probably written by programmers who are better than you or I. Certainly 10 years on most of the bugs have been found. So why not take advantage of that skill and experience and use the simpler URLConnection.

Comment: Sockets do not use http - is that it? And URLConnection contains sockets for preform the http requests?

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter which one is faster both of these have different purposes. A socket is an endpoint for communication between two machines and need to access different protocol. Class URL represents a Uniform Resource Locator, a pointer to a "resource" on the World Wide Web. A resource can be something as simple as a file or a directory, or it can be a reference to a more complicated object, such as a query to a database or to a search engine. 
   In short if you need to communicate with the other machine or device implement socket and if you want to read data from server use URLconnection.

Happy Coding :D

Answer (score -1):

Although it depends on the type of data, server etc.
I agree with r0ast3d.

According to me if server allows both the things, then I would prefer to use URLConnection.
Both sends data using streams, but wait mode in Socket is bit high than in URLConnection.

Please correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: Also URLConnection is higher level class that provides you with a lot of build in functionality compared to Socket

Comment: 'Wait mode in Socket', whatever that might be, is identical to that in URLConnection, as URLConnections always use sockets.

Answer (score -1):

From tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/connecting.html
URLConnection IS NOT abstract and can be instanciated

Would love to see some benchmarks on which one is faster though.

Comment: From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) it most certainly is abstract, and there is nothing in your link that says otherwise, or that shows that it can be instantiated directly.