# What's difference between urlconnection and socket class?

Tags: java, sockets, connection

I am new to java.I know class urlconnection is a class to connect to internet in java.I want to know why we use socket class for this issue too.what's differences between them and witch on is better?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177628/which-is-fast-urlconnection-or-socket

Comment: Asking for the difference between them are not the same thing as asking which one is faster. It would be great for everybody if you could read the questions before closing them

Answer (score 0):

Socket is low level than urlconnection. Url connection can use a socket to connect with HTTP protocole.